# Android JSON conversion issue

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

[Here is the string failing to convert] and[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARmKP.png)[EDIT: Here is the logcat of my error][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL0zC.png) I'm currently trying to implement a login for my app, which has a login, login request, register and register request activities. In my register activity,I send the user data back to my database, but when I try to do this on my device, I get an error in the Android Monitor that reads 
"org.json.JSONException: Value

I'm using MySQL and 000Webhost for my database and hosting. Below is the code which I think may have something to do with the error, but I'm not quite sure. If anyone can help here, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
touristRegisterBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String touristName = touristNameRegET.getText().toString();
            final String touristEmail = touristEmailRegET.getText().toString();
            final String touristPassword = touristPasswordRegET.getText().toString();


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(touristRegister.this, touristLogin.class);
                            touristRegister.this.startActivity(intent);

                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(touristRegister.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Registration failed!")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }`
```

Comment: Please post string response and logcat

Comment: Hi, just edited my question to include the image. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: And the string response. that is what android failed to convert into json. As shown in the logcat, the string is not in JSON format, so a json exception is inevitable

Comment: My apologies, I think I've added what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat says `<br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` which basically means that the string you are trying to parse as a JSON string is not a JSON string. By the looks of it, it's an HTML document.

Basically the `response` variable is not valid to be converted. You're either pointing to the wrong URL, or the server is returning the wrong data. If you're unsure as to what a JSON string should look like, here's an example

```
{
    "username": "myusername",
    "token": "JD297H48FUO2J048JF729F2",
    "wadus": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "timestamp": 123144535143,
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: Ah, now I'm beginning to see it. It's probably running into the error trying to read back from my database. Thank you.

Comment: Done and done. As an update, for those who may be interested, this error actually came from one of the php files used to connect my app to my database, more specifically, still having an int declared in my ' mysqli_stmt_bind_param' method after I had removed it from my Login Form.